# Django & X-editable does not function

Tags: django, templates, x-editable

I am trying to apply X-editable with bootstrap in my django template.

I follow the basic tutorial from this link https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html

and I have created my main.js file that has got javascript in it. 
I have placed right code in my template but when I click on username and try to edit it nothing happens.

any ideas why ?
part of my template code :::

```
    </table>

    <div class="container">

      <h1>X-editable starter template</h1>

      <div>
        <span>Username:</span>
        <a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-placement="right" data-title="Enter username">superuser</a>
      </div>

      <div>
        <span>Status:</span>
        <a href="#" id="status">Status Test</a>
      </div>


    </div>


        <!-- bootstrap -->
        <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

        <!-- x-editable (bootstrap version) -->
        <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-editable.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-editable.min.js' %}"></script>

        <!-- main.js -->
        <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/collapse.js' %}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

and javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';

      $('#username').editable({
        type: 'text',
        title: 'Enter username',
        success: function(response, newValue) {
            userModel.set('username', newValue); //update backbone model
        }
    });

    //make status editable
    $('#status').editable({
        type: 'select',
        title: 'Select status',
        placement: 'right',
        value: 2,
        source: [
            {value: 1, text: 'status 1'},
            {value: 2, text: 'status 2'},
            {value: 3, text: 'status 3'}
        ]
        /*
        //uncomment these lines to send data on server
        ,pk: 1
        ,url: '/post'
        */
    });
});
```

Comment: any console errors ?

Comment: not at all when I click 'superuser' ...

Comment: when I click it the link in the browser changes to http://localhost:8000/main/# from this one http://localhost:8000/main/

Comment: any possibility to have a plunker for this ?

Comment: I have never used plunker before ...

Comment: any other tool ? JsFiddle,codepen or else?

Comment: I created this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jub4w4z9/) from your code only and it works as expected. And, on a separate note I would strongly recommend to move your css inside `<head>` tag instead of using inside `<body>`.

Comment: hi, I have cleared my html files and put css & js in right locations and now it all works fine. thanks

Comment: and my problem was that I assigned id=username to all cells in my table and have not noticed I could edit first one only but not all the others because of the same id.